# Is it at all commonplace to make service available via the same host as its redundancy, just different ports?

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, routing, high-availability

I am writing software that allows for the configuration of parameters for authentication with a Primary and Secondary RADIUS server.

Server administrators, in your experience, is it common or not for a network to be laid out such that — either physically or accomplished by clever routing, as I can envision load balancing or somesuch leading to this — a primary service may live at Host1:Port1 and its redundant backup on Host1:Port2?

Or should I simply ban users from configuring a Primary and Secondary on the same host, regardless of port number?

Comment: In development environments I could see this being the case due to resource constraints, but the concept of HA is to resilient against host failure...

Comment: Possible? Probably, for some cases. I can say though that I've seen this being tried on a development environment where the software simply would not allow it. As for commonplace? Definitely not.

Comment: @NathanC: I just figured it was plausible for the HA server or load balancer to expose services on a single host and redirect traffic to the actual distinct physical services as it sees fit. Of course then the single host itself has no redundancy. Lol.

Comment: @Reaces: Would you prefer the software to allow it for those cases where you want to be able to do it? Or do you think banning it entirely is reasonable?

Comment: As the person usually responsible for deploying to production, with all the "it works in development" problems that come with it, I'd vote for barring the possibility all together. As I can't imagine a production environment that requires it. However I imagine opinions will vary depending on who you ask.

Comment: @Reaces I agree ...and because of the opinion nature of the question I've tossed a close vote on the question as well.

Comment: Configuring "redundant" services on the same host is a bad production practice that may be convenient in development. Don't prohibit it (send a warning, if you must).